# Laravel WhereNotIn using multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to do the following mysql query:

> where (a.contact_id,b.contact_id) 
>   not in( select contact1_id,contact2_id from comparisons )

In Laravel it seems impossible to use multiple columns in whereNotIn 
I tried this:

```
->whereNotIn('a.contact_id, b.contact_id',function($query)
{
$query->select('contact1_id','contact2_id')
    ->from('comparisons')
})
```

But it doesn't work...
Any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `DB::raw` to pass two columns:

```php
$query->whereNotIn( DB::raw('(a.contact_id, b.contact_id)'), function($query)
{
    $query->select('contact1_id','contact2_id')
          ->from('comparisons');
});
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using raw... but I guess it's the only solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: But for it to work, it has to be DB::raw('(a.contact_id, b.contact_id)')